# Which positive integers $n$ can be expressed as $n=a^2+b^2+c^2$ , but not with positive $a,b,c\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, square-numbers

Let $S$ be the set of positive integers $n$, such that the equation $$a^2+b^2+c^2=n$$ has a solution in non-negative integers but not in positive integers. Since $n\in S$ if and only if $4n\in S$, we can assume that $n$ is not divisble by $4$. Also, $n\equiv 3\mod 4$ can be ruled out because a number of the form $8k+3$ is always the sum of three positive squares and a number of the form $8k+7$ is not the sum of three squares.

The first positive integers in $S$ not being divisble by $4$, are :

$$[1, 2, 5, 10, 13, 25, 37, 58, 85, 130]$$

I did not find further such integers yet.

> Is this list complete ? If not , how can I classify the numbers being in $S$ ?

Comment: [Relevant OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A051952)?

Comment: Isn't $9$ in $S$?

Comment: Also of course $n\equiv 3\bmod 4$ isn't _always_ the sum of three positive squares (e.g. $n=7$); I presume the meaning there is that it's never the sum of one or two squares?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry, I got this wrong, I meant a number of the form $8k+3$. I edited the question

Comment: $9$ is not in $S$ because we have $9=2^2+2^2+1^2$

Comment: To clarify the question : I search all numbers that are the sum of at most three squares (not of the form $4^n\cdot (8k+7)$) , but have no representation as a sum of three positive squares.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A051952 says this is an open problem.

Comment: In particular, I wonder whether the equation $p^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$ has a solution in positive integers $a,b,c$ for every prime $p\equiv 3\mod 4$. Is this known ?

Comment: @Peter, $p=7$ is a counterexample. See https://oeis.org/A007522.

Comment: I do not understand : $$7^2=6^2+3^2+2^2$$

Comment: $n=7$ not $n=49$.

Comment: But $n=7$ is of the form $8k+7$ which is not in S. And in the comment, I meant the squares of the pirmes, not the primes themselve.